# drupal 7 workbench: Can I limit different users/roles within a particular section via taxonomy?

Tags: workflows, workbench

drupal 7 workbench: Can I limit different users/roles within a particular section via taxonomy?
If I setup 2 roles Author and Editor and I assign different users with the same role (i.e. Author) but assign them to a different section via taxonomy (i.e. Northeast region or Southwest region).  Once this is done will users with Northeast region taxonomy and Editor role only see "Needs Review" documents within the Workbench section created by Author user that have the matching Northeast region taxonomy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the submodule of [Workbench](http://www.drupal.org/project/workbench), called [Workbench Access](http://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) to limit users to a "sub section" of the content based on Taxonomy or Menu path.

> Workbench Access creates editorial access controls based on
>   hierarchies. It is an extensible system that supports structures
>   created by other Drupal modules.
>
> When creating and editing content, users will be asked to place the
>   content in an editorial section. Other users within that section or
>   its parents will be able to edit the content. A user may be granted
>   editorial rights to a section specific to his account or by his
>   assigned role on the site.

There is a [great documentation page and associated web video for Workbench Access](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/workbench_access) on configuration within the project page.